# Check a date (datetime) if it is Daylight Saving Time with unknown region - c#

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, dst

With what I understood from other questions I've used below code for checking a date if it is Daylight saving time and altering as required. I do not know which region would the application be used hence I am using Utc. However it is not working as expected.

```
DateTime dateValWithOffset = dateVal;
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;

if(timeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(dateValWithOffset))
{
 dateValWithOffset = dateValWithOffset.AddMinutes(60);
}
```

Example: for **sample date (06-JUL-21 06.16.34.547000000 AM)** above code should be showing dateValWithOffset  as **07/06/2021 02:16:34.547 AM**  but it returns  **07/06/2021 01:16:34.547 AM** . If someone can point out where am I going wrong please.

Comment: UTC is universal, so there is no daylight saving.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith but all the data is saved in UTC and no regional data is saved for reference , so isn't there any way to check for the same ?

Comment: You can't apply daylight saving rules if you don't know the timezone/region.  As every timezone has different rules.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith if i have a timezoneoffsett then ? like 300 . then can we use that to get the timezone ?

Comment: The offset will not tell you the timezone. You need time zone info for that. Most cases it's enough to save as UTC and only translate to local (browser) time on the UI.

Comment: *point out where am I going wrong* - what you ask is nearly impossible, sorry. It's like asking "I have a number, and it's something to do with a person: 78 - what is it?" - could be age in years, wight in kg, height in inches, the number of the house they live at, the number of goldfish they've ever owned..

Comment: Saving in UTC isn't enough. You *assume* all applications and all code in an application will always store UTC. Even if that works, you still don't know what DST rules applied to that value, nor can you guess it by comparing with the current local time. If you used a `DateTimeOffset` things would be a little better (no offset assumptions) but still no DST rules. The defacto standard for dealing with this is to use the IANA timezone rules and names, eg `Europe/London`, `America/New_York`. That's why you see these options in many web sites

Comment: Time and calendars are a lot more complex than just a time and offset. In .NET you can use NodaTime to represent instants and handle timezones using the IANA timezone database

Comment: Using `DateTimeOffset` is enough to display the value as local time without adjustments in any timezone but it's not enough to tell you whether DST applies or not. If the DST rules of the original timezone change (which happens a lot more frequently than one would assume), the DateTimeOffset value would have to be adjusted. So would a UTC value of course. Russia has changed DST rules twice in the last 10 years. Egypt abruptly changed its DST rules with only a few weeks notice

Comment: Where You're going wrong is that you do not represent your data in a format that has information about what timezone it is from, store on the user or customer for instance their timeZoneId or let their browser pick it up using javascript, the offset that is and consider some of the techniques and pitfalls i tried walking through below

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  can we extract zone from atleast a string containing that data 12/20/2021 02:11:03 AM EST ?? from this time can we extraxt est time zone info and then create a TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("EST"); someting like this ?

Comment: @ShaliniRaj - Unfortunately, time zone abbreviations are not reliable for this.  Consider "CST" which could mean "Central Standard Time", "Cuba Standard Time" or "China Standard Time".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Datetime` values should *always* be in UTC. To format a datetime in the machine or user's local timezone, you should convert to a `DateTimeOffset`. Knowing the local time and knowing if that time is in daylight saving time are two different things.

```cs
// machine local
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
// or by name
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(name);
var localTime = new DateTimeOffset(dateVal, timeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(dateVal));
var isDst = timeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(localTime)
```

IMHO `DateTime` is a terrible type, designed before the age of cloud computing. All `DateTimeKind` values other than `Utc` encourage programmers to continue to handle dates incorrectly and should be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

As `jason.kaisersmith` said in comments, "UTC is universal, so there is no daylight saving."

To elaborate, UTC does not have any daylight saving time.  Instead, daylight saving time is observed differently at each time zone across the world.  Some time zones don't use it at all.  Some time zones start and stop DST at different dates or times than other time zones.  There's even [one time zone](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/australia/lord-howe-island) that shifts for DST by 30 minutes instead of the usual 1 hour.  Without a time zone reference, the concept of DST is meaningless.

For clarity and reference, [here's an overview of anticipated DST dates for 2022 by country](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2022.html), and a detailed list of dates and times for the [first half](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2022a.html) and [second half](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2022b.html) of 2022.